# Preserving blank space in an Array java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to preserve blank spaces, periods, commas, exclamation marks, and new lines in the process of placing each into an array. All but the blank space are working just fine.

```
Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(file);
 while (fileInput.hasNext()) 
  {
    String s = fileInput.next();
    if(s.endsWith(",") || s.endsWith(".") || s.endsWith("!")|| s.endsWith("\n") || s.endsWith(","))
    {
        String token = new String("");
        token += s.charAt(s.length()-1);
        s = s.substring(0, s.length()-1);
        words.add(s.toLowerCase());
        words.add(token);
    }

    else if (!s.equals("") )        
      words.add(s.toLowerCase());        
  }

}
```

Comment: There's no condition for `endsWith(" ")` in you `if` statement

Comment: `Scanner`'s `next` method skips over white space, so you can't use it.  Use `nextLine`, which will give you an entire line without modifying it or skipping over anything.

Comment: @ajb This needs to be answer!

Comment: @MadProgrammer - I Second your opinion.. *ajb*'s comment is indeed the answer.

Comment: Well, it's not a complete answer.  I don't think he can just change `next` to `nextLine`; more work has to be done.

Comment: @ajb It certainly answers the immediate problem, better then the other answers ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next()` reads input until space occurs excluding space.So for blank your code won't work as blank is actually not there moreover you can use `charAt` to fetch last character and use `switch` instead of `||`.

You should use `nextLine()` to fetch all the tokens (Suggested by `TheLostMind` as well) including spaces inbetween for your convinience.

Comment: also use `nextLine()` to get *space-delimited* words.

Comment: `token = s.charAt(s.length() - 1);` won't work as `String` is not compatible with `char`, `String token = s.substring(s.length() - 1);` would achieve the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Scanner can return spaces. You just need to use a delimiter<sup>1</sup>. Try the following.

```
Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(file);
fileInput.useDelimiter("(?<=(\\s++))");
while (fileInput.hasNext())
```

Of course you need to add some conditions to see if a string ends with space or new line character.

<sub>**NOTES**</sub>

<sub><sup>1</sup> The key is to find a good delimiter that meets your requirements.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

just give some space between `("")` like `(" ")` and make use of `nextLine()` for taking input  BECAUSE see the following code

```
public class MyClass{
public static void main(String args[])
{
if("".equals(" "))    //THIS BLOCK WILL NOT RUN
{
System.out.println("same");
}
else{                     //ELSE PART WILL BE EXECUTED
 System.out.println("NOT SAME");
}
}
}
```

**OUTPUT: NOT SAME**

blank space is a character literal with ascii code 32.

Comment: This will cause extra spaces to be added.

Comment: `else if (!s.equals("")) ` is checking for blank lines